# How to Call Another Module in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I Have an Issue to call Another Module (Run Time Error'424': Object Required). I have 2 Modules, Module 1 and Module 2. And Below is the code in Module 1 :

```
Private Sub test()

 Dim Work As Worksheet: Set work= Sheets("S_BDN")

 For i = 1 To 2

 Set f = work.Range("A5", work.Range("A5").End(xlDown))
 Set a = f.Find(i, LookIn:=xlValues)
        

    If a.Offset(0, 10).Value = "January" Then
        Call Module3.Proceed_B
    End If

 Next i
End Sub
```

And Below is the code in Module 2 :

```
sub Module3.Proceed_B()

 If a.Offset(0, 6).Value = "A" Then
      Debug.Print a.Offset(0, 4).Value
 else
      Debug.Print a.Offset(0, 5).Value
 end if

end sub
```

All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Start by adding `Option Explicit` at the top of each module, declare all your variables, and remove the `Module3` from the procedure name and call.

Comment: Then read up on variable scope in VBA  - eg see https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/variable-scope.html

Comment: Thank you so much @TimWilliams, The Error is Solved, but there is another issue, The Result In Module 2, "Debug.Print a.Offset(0, 4).Value" , It Appears 2 datas but Same Data Not Different Data, I try to Substitute  "Call Module3.Proceed_B" to  "Debug.Print a.Offset(0, 4).Value" in same module (Module 1) , it works , I mean, The results are 2 Datas and different. or My Looping is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your "fixed" code or your sheet, so here are some generic suggestions for improvement:

```vb
Private Sub test()

   Dim Work As Worksheet, f As Range, a As Range
   Set work= Sheets("S_BDN")
   
   Set f = work.Range("A5", work.Range("A5").End(xlDown)) 'take out of loop

   For i = 1 To 2
 
     Set a = Nothing
     Set a = f.Find(i, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) 'provide *all* relevant parameters
     If Not a Is Nothing Then                      'make sure you got a match   
         If a.Offset(0, 10).Value = "January" Then
             Proceed_B a   'pass a to the other sub
         End If
     End If

 Next i
End Sub

sub Proceed_B(a As Range)
   If a.Offset(0, 6).Value = "A" Then
      Debug.Print a.Offset(0, 4).Value
   else
      Debug.Print a.Offset(0, 5).Value
   end if
end sub
```